# How to send token by contract with python?

Tags: python, tron

I want to send trc20 token by `tronapi` lib but my code doesn't work.
I don't have any error but it doesn't work :(

```
from tronapi import Tron
from tronapi import HttpProvider
    
full_node = HttpProvider('https://nile.trongrid.io')
solidity_node = HttpProvider('https://nile.trongrid.io')
event_server = HttpProvider('https://nile.trongrid.io')
    
tron = Tron(full_node=full_node,
            solidity_node=solidity_node,
            event_server=event_server)
    
tron.private_key = '59d4b72df50290d7f78e2c16fc27758d6e235f3959f2212f2497fc55da33e888'
tron.default_address = 'TRNDt7bjFoTq7p52iw5u2BLNhsff1ux7Fc'
Towallet = 'TFgmQmr31HxkiZ67KBjwZPseT1G5t4tWdT'
Amount = 11
usernum = 20
Tcontract='TXLAQ63Xg1NAzckPwKHvzw7CSEmLMEqcdj'
send = tron.transaction_builder.trigger_smart_contract(
    contract_address=tron.address.to_hex(Tcontract),
    function_selector='transfer(address, uint256)',
    fee_limit=30000000,
    call_value=0,
    parameters=[
        {'type': 'address', 'value': tron.address.to_hex(Towallet)},
        {'type': 'int256', 'value': int(float(Amount)*pow(10,6))}
    ]
)
print(send)
```

the result:

```
{'result': {'result': True}, 'transaction': {'visible': False, 'txID': '2379e197670790c00c30b170e42c61e7f6040779e055790f8f41627170849ee2', 'raw_data': {'contract': [{'parameter': {'value': {'data': 'a9059cbb0000000000000000000000003eb4bca6f3d6791a6e044af18ae0889ea82307210000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a7d8c0', 'owner_address': '41a8e4304def45a15814272a8738225b9edc42081b', 'contract_address': '41ea51342dabbb928ae1e576bd39eff8aaf070a8c6'}, 'type_url': 'type.googleapis.com/protocol.TriggerSmartContract'}, 'type': 'TriggerSmartContract'}], 'ref_block_bytes': 'a7ac', 'ref_block_hash': '50d0abab544c57c0', 'expiration': 1671983553000, 'fee_limit': 30000000, 'timestamp': 1671983495561}, 'raw_data_hex': '0a02a7ac220850d0abab544c57c040e8b3f1cfd4305aae01081f12a9010a31747970652e676f6f676c65617069732e636f6d2f70726f746f636f6c2e54726967676572536d617274436f6e747261637412740a1541a8e4304def45a15814272a8738225b9edc42081b121541ea51342dabbb928ae1e576bd39eff8aaf070a8c62244a9059cbb0000000000000000000000003eb4bca6f3d6791a6e044af18ae0889ea82307210000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a7d8c07089f3edcfd43090018087a70e'}}
```

Comment: Pls share the desired output and current output.

Comment: also wrap you code with try catch blocks

Comment: You should probably delete the question and remove the private keys, if they are valid..

Comment: no this privatekey is not valid it's just for testnet